# Getting the 2nd highest salary after dpt ID input

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I am trying to write this PL SQL query to get the second highest salary out of the table after input of the dpt ID.
I put this together but the query does not run after the input of the dpt ID.

```
CREATE TABLE OUTPUT_LOG
  (my_column VARCHAR(250)); 
DECLARE
    v_dpt_id
BEGIN
    select dpt_id
        into v_dpt_id
    from employees
    where dpt_id = inticap('&prompt_user');
    select salary from
     (select rownum n,a.* from
        ( select distinct salary from employees order by salary desc) a)
where n = 2;
    insert into output_log (my_column)
    VALUES (||first_name||' '||last_name||' '||salary||);
end;
SELECT my_column
  FROM OUTPUT_LOG;
```

Comment: tell me use of v_dpt_id variable which is out from employees table.

Answer (score 0):

try this

you can simply change query as like

```
select * from employees where salary in 
(
   select salary from
     (select rownum n,a.* from
        ( select distinct salary from employees where dpt_id = initcap('&prompt_user') order by salary desc) a
        )
     where n = 2
)
```

this query give all employees which have secode highest salary on their department.

i hope this may help.

Comment: Mark as best answers or upvote me if answer is perfect.